# WCF callback timeout and Visual Studio catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, duplex

A kind of stupid error, but this happened when I wanted to call client by server-side-service (WCF Duplex):

> The message could not be transferred within the allotted wcf callback timeout of 00:01:00, There was no space available in the reliable channel's transfer window

Also something `mysterious happened too`. In the login method when I called service if user and password be wrong I find sender-callback and then call `GetError` method on sender to show logical error like "User is wrong". This works well, but if user and password is correct and have access, I got that error (same for all other client-side methods - in all these methods I send more data than simple strings, I was send geterror) !

**Edit 2:** As I say in most of the callback methods, I was send data like data-context (LINQ to SQL) data-class (list or single row). So might this be my problem or not!
(But this isn't my first time, using WCF-duplex, also with send data-struct in callback methods , I'm so astounding.)

Also after that error I got this error on,

> Screen unable to process request from service http://server:15450/service.svc catastrophic failure

**Edit 3:**
Service configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ContactServer.Business.ContactService"
               behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                  contract="ContactServer.Business.IContactService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  name="MexBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and **Client Config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ContactService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1408/ContactService.svc"
        binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ContactService"
        contract="ServiceReference.ContactService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ContactService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**More information:** I use .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2010. Also after rising timeout on the client side I still got the same error, `with 00:01:00 Time`. Why did this happen?

Comment: @Rev: This story is fancy but what we need is more information about your service - service and callback behaviors, service and callback contracts, etc. Also about type of your client application. Btw. don't send DataContext over WCF - it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you have a famous problem in WPF or Silverlight, where you should specify ConcurrencyMode=Reentrant.

Comment: @Ladislav: I don't send total data-context over service or callback, only send one or two data-class(single row or list<entity>).

Comment: Have you tried to call the service without security mode? Just with standard settings. Also ConcurrencyMode shouldn't change anything, find an exact error why client can't call the service.

Comment: There are attributes "security" and "reliableSession" in the client config. Tags "identity" are redundant too. Try to delete them. And set ConcurrencyMode=Multiple or Reentrant, because Single isn't a good choice.

Comment: @Rev Another reason could be a serialization. I had a similar problem with EF when I sent an entity but serializer tried to serialize all relations. In your example I would try to pass a simple unreal object, and if it works without errors - search mistakes in the datacontext.

Comment: @Vorrtex: thanks. After your comment I delete all relation between tables only in dataclasses and all callbacks work fine! so can you post comment as answer and give me more informatuion about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is concerning transfer of entities from a WCF-service.

For example, we have this database model:
[image]

**Entity Framework:**

```
    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        var se = new SampleEntities();
        return se.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    }
```

The code doesn't seem to be wrong, but in reality it will return the item with all related items.

```
        var s = new SampleServiceClient();
        var item = s.GetItem(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(item.RelatedItems.Any(), true); //equal
```

It is especially dangerous if we have many-to-many relations in the database.
So lazy loading should be disabled (you can disable them just before the return):

```
var se = new SampleEntities();
se.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
return se.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
```

**Linq to SQL**

```
    public Item GetItem(int id)
    {
        var dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        return dc.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    }
```

We have an exception:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter :GetItemResult. The InnerException message was 'Object graph for type 'WebApplication1.RelatedItem' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.'.

You must open DataContext diagramm and set Properties->SerializationMode->Unindirectional. [Here](http://www.codeexperiment.com/post/Returning-LINQ-to-SQL-Entities-From-WCF.aspx) is a more complete explanation.

Comment: certainly problem rise from DataContext